# C# - Ferramenta que permita assinatura num documento PDF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, pdf

Preciso  de uma ferramenta que me permita  que uma pessoa possa assinar um documento PDF num determinado local do documento, alguém tem alguma dica? Mas tem que permitir fazer isso internamente na minha aplicação, ferramentas como o Adobe Sign, que usam Cloud para isso não pode ser(é um requisito).

Basicamente o requsito é no meio do processo vai abrir um  PDF num tablet a pessoa lê e assina como se fosse um papel.

Obrigado

Comment: [Veja se ajuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388927/drawing-on-pdf-file-c-sharp#8388968)

Comment: Então essa implementação eu fiz e exatamente usando o iTextSharp gerei  um PDF com o campo em retângulo  para assinatura mas ai eu queria poder assinar num tablet por exemplo dentro desse retângulo.

Comment: Não estou familiarizado com C# nem suas bibliotecas, mas podes também gerar uma imagem da página que pretendes assinar e usar um canvas para desenhar na mesma.

Comment: Pode ser uma hipótese, obrigado.